# Optional hash option in Ruby class

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to configure a driver with Capybara where an options hash is only used via an environment variable.

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
opts.add_argument '--start-maximized'
opts.add_argument '--disable-infobars'
opts.add_argument '--headless' if ENV['headless']
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(accept_insecure_certs: true, proxy: proxy, browserName: 'chrome' if ENV['extra_args])
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    options: opts,
    desired_capabilities: caps
)
  end

  Capybara.app_host = location
  Capybara.default_driver = :chrome
end
```

This is the line I'm working on:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(accept_insecure_certs: true, proxy: proxy, browserName: 'chrome' if ENV['extra_args])
```

I know this is invalid syntax but is there a way I can achieve what it is I am trying to do here? `browserName` needs to only be invoked if the `ENV[extra_args']` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any  of the `Capabilities` keys via `#[]=`, with the key in snake case so

```
...
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(accept_insecure_certs: true, proxy: proxy)
caps['browser_name'] = 'chrome' if ENV['extra_args']
...
```

would work but there's also a `browser_name=` method on `Capabilities` so

```
...
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(accept_insecure_certs: true, proxy: proxy)
caps.browser_name = 'chrome' if ENV['extra_args']
...
```

probably makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
options = {accept_insecure_certs: true, proxy: proxy}
options.merge!({browserName: 'chrome'}) if ENV['extra_args]
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(options)
```

Let me know if it helps!